# how to add a Hashset to a javax.ws.rs.core.Response in java

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jax-rs

I'm trying to embed a hashset to the entity of a  javax.ws.rs.core.Response

For example:

```
@GET
@Path("someting...")
@Produces("application/xml")
public Response getStuff( ... ...) {
    Set<customisedClass> stuff = retrieveMethod(xx);
    return Response.ok().entity(stuff).build()
```

This would give me:

```
Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: java.util.HashSet of media type: application/xml
```

Does anyone know how I should do this ? The "customisedClass" has already been annotated correctly.

Thanks

Comment: You mean that you have annotated the CustomizedClass with @XMLElement and other JAXB elements?

Comment: @KarthikR yeah, it seems to work fine if i try to embed only one customisedClass object. I can then use readEntity(customisedClass.class) to get the object without any issue...so it seems that it has something to do with the Hashset i guess.

Comment: Usually you wrap the collection elements inside another class. I will post one  as answer check if it can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably wrap the collection inside another class that would resemble the following XML:

```
<employees>
   <employee>
      <name>Gates</name>
   </employee>
   <employee>
      <name>Bill</name>
   </employee>
<employees>
```

To achieve this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "employees")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employees
{
    @XmlElement(name = "employee")
    private Set<Employee> employees = null;

    public Set<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(Set<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }
}
```

Then you set the Employees to the Response object. This is the usual way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine now. Btw, I'm just wondering if there are any other ways of achieving this (without creating a new class) ?